# javascript msgbox if statement

Tags: javascript, vb.net

I have a two JavaScript message boxs in an if statement which arent firing - the compiler just bypasses the code as if its not there. This exact same code works elsewhere when its outside the if statement. Can anyone shed some light as to why this isnt working? Thanks

```
If chk1.Checked And chk4.Checked Then

    Dim message As String = "Invalid"
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
    sb.Append("alert('")
    sb.Append(message)
    sb.Append("')};")
    sb.Append("</script>")

    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString())
Else
    If chk2.Checked = True And chk5.Checked = True Then
        Dim message2 As String = "Invalid"
        Dim sb2 As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
        sb2.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
        sb2.Append("window.onload=function(){")
        sb2.Append("alert('")
        sb2.Append(message2)
        sb2.Append("')};")
        sb2.Append("</script>")

        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb2.ToString())
    Else
```

Comment: Where's the rest of the `If/Else`? Also: **this will break if the message contains an apostrophe.** (I realize that your example doesn't.)

Comment: I didnt think the rest of the statement was relevant... it works fine - the code I posted is where the issue lies

Comment: Where are you emitting this code? In an `OnClick` handler? In the `Page_Load` handler?

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
sb2.Append("</script>")
```

With:

```
sb2.Append("<\/script>")
```

in both conditions.

Browser does not allow direct injection, you need to trick it.

---

I wonder why you are mixing Javascript and VBScript together or how it is gonna run.

Comment: Question tagged with `VB.NET`. It's an server side code on `Visual Basic .Net` language.

Comment: @Sarfraz: I clicked on the arrow after reading _"I wonder why you are mixing Javascript and VBScript together or how it is gonna run."_ Now I can not undo the vote. Site say "Your vote is now locked in unless this answer is edited".

Comment: This isn't injection, it's being emitted on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your onload event isn't setting the checkboxes. [The ASP.net lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) specifies that the onload event will fire first and therefore set the checkboxes to what is defined in the onload section. If you need to avoid this, just wrap the code that sets the checkboxes in a 
`if not isPostback then` statement to avoid this from happening

Answer (score 0):

aspx:

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />
<br />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" Text="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" Text="CheckBox2" runat="server" />
```

vb:

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim message As String = "not (chk1 and chk2)"
    If CheckBox1.Checked And CheckBox2.Checked Then
        message = "chk1 and chk2"
    Else
        If CheckBox1.Checked Then
            message = "chk1"
        ElseIf CheckBox2.Checked Then
            message = "chk2"
        End If
    End If
    Dim sb As New System.Text.StringBuilder()
    sb.Append("<script type = 'text/javascript'>")
    sb.Append("window.onload=function(){")
    sb.Append("alert('")
    sb.Append(message)
    sb.Append("')};")
    sb.Append("</script>")
    ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "alert", sb.ToString())
End Sub
```

i tested this code ....

Answer (score -2):

try == rather than = in if condition!

Comment: That's not the case with VBScript.

Comment: @hardik:-in VB condition is checked with = not ==